# Read and parse a Json File in C# by JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

**I have JSON file like:**

```
        {
          "50": {
            "docid": "5611",
            "code": "ГОСТ 11529-2016",
            "name": "Материалы поливинилхлоридные для полов. Методы контроля",
            "type_id": "6",
            "status": "0"
          },
          "51": {
            "docid": "509",
            "code": "ГОСТ 11583-74",
            "name": "Материалы полимерные строительные отделочные. Методы определения цветоустойчивости под воздействием света, равномерности окраски и светлоты",
            "type_id": "6",
            "status": "0"
          },
          ...................................................................................
          "4000": {
            "docid": "5611",
            "code": "ГОСТ 11529-2016",
            "name": "Материалы поливинилхлоридные для полов. Методы контроля",
            "type_id": "6",
            "status": "0"
          },

       }
```

**And  Code:**

```
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Json.json"))
            {
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UpL>>(json);
                foreach(var item in items)
                {
                    foreach (var i in item)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i.name);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public class UpL 
        {
            public Item item { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            [JsonProperty("docid")] public string docid;
            [JsonProperty("code")] public string code;
            [JsonProperty("name")] public string name;
            [JsonProperty("status")] public string status;
            [JsonProperty("type_id")] public string type_id;
        }
```

**Error:type object cannot be used in foreach statements.**

What should be rewritten in the code to avoid this error.
How do I parse this JSON correctly?
I need to get all items from the Item class.

Comment: What type is items in the debugger ?

Comment: This is because it is not a `List<UpL>` but rather a `Dictionary<string, UpL>`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya His classes are fine, he's just deserializing it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes... You are right @ThePerplexedOne

Comment: Dictionary<string, UpL> gives error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException - Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Comment: Ah. I don't think the `UpL` class is necessary. You can deserialize your JSON as `Dictionary<string, Item>`. I was slightly wrong with my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I may have been slightly wrong in my first comment.

I don't think the `UpL` class is necessary.

You can deserialize your JSON as `Dictionary<string, Item>` instead of a `List<T>`:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

This was a mistake I also made when I came across this kind of JSON.

Now, if you only want the items, you can run some LINQ on it to only select those:

```
var items = dict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Here's my working example:

```
        var json = @"{
      ""50"": {
        ""docid"": ""5611"",
        ""code"": ""ГОСТ 11529-2016"",
        ""name"": ""Материалы поливинилхлоридные для полов. Методы контроля"",
        ""type_id"": ""6"",
        ""status"": ""0""
      },
      ""51"": {
        ""docid"": ""509"",
        ""code"": ""ГОСТ 11583-74"",
        ""name"": ""Материалы полимерные строительные отделочные. Методы определения цветоустойчивости под воздействием света, равномерности окраски и светлоты"",
        ""type_id"": ""6"",
        ""status"": ""0""
      },
      ""4000"": {
        ""docid"": ""5611"",
        ""code"": ""ГОСТ 11529-2016"",
        ""name"": ""Материалы поливинилхлоридные для полов. Методы контроля"",
        ""type_id"": ""6"",
        ""status"": ""0""
      }
   }";
        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
        var items = dict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Comment: It works fine for me. You've either done it wrong, or your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The json having keyvaluepair. The class `UpL` is not required. DeserializeObject as Dictionary

```
        using (var r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Json.json"))
        {
            var json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
            foreach (var keyValuePair in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Value.name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Item>>>(json);   solve this, thank u sir

Comment: @RkCelsius Right, so you conveniently left out the fact that it's an array of dictionaries and not just a single dictionary. Provide your full JSON next time.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOn, sir, i provide full JSON file.

Comment: @RkCelsius You clearly haven't, otherwise my code would work and `List<Dictionary<string, Item>>` would not.